# How-To get consecutive id with RavenDb default id generator

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb

I'm evaluating RavenDB for a new project.

If i create 100 entities i got great consecutive ids like :

- posts/1
- posts/2
- posts/3
- ...
- posts/100

But if i build a new DocumentStore instance (after App Restart) and try to create new entities i got strange ids like this :

- posts/1025
- posts/1026
- posts/1027

Any help ?

Note : I'm using Embedded Server with ASP.NET MVC 3

Comment: If consecutive IDs matter to you, you're generally doing something wrong.

Comment: Seems reasonable to me, at times. Eg, invoice numbers are expected to be sequential, unique and unchanging. Seems like a reasonable identity in some cases. Or would you *always* use a surrogate id, and then manually generate sequential invoice numbers some other way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is by design - new HiLo keys are generated whenever you create a DocumentStore instance, so the gaps you are seeing are the unused ids from the other session.

Why do you care for consecutive ids?

This may be a good read on the subject, too: http://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/3dbcacbc8b366ff8/

Answer (score 7):

From the RavenDb documents, [you're after the Identity strategy](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/basic-operations/saving-new-document).

> RavenDB also supports the notion of Identity, for example if you need
>   IDs to be consecutive. By creating a string Id property in your
>   entity, and setting it to a value ending with a slash (/), you can
>   tell RavenDB to use that as a key perfix for your entity. That prefix
>   followed by the next available integer ID for it will be your entity's
>   ID after you call SaveChanges().

eg.

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.Id = "foo/"; // <-- this will use the Identity strategy, not HiLo.

session.Store(foo);
session.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at the identity option for RavenDB, but that isn't really something that you should care about.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an identifier by your client, while still relying on the server to generate the identifier for you. It is done using the NextIdentityForCommand command:

```
var command = new NextIdentityForCommand("<<your collection name>>");
Session.Advanced.RequestExecutor.Execute(command, Session.Advanced.Context);
var id = command.Result;
```

This way you can use the identity value even in different field from Id. On the other hand, this makes creating a document slower, because you have to approach a server twice.